# xpath how to get quantity of links on page?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For example I searching for something in google, than I get search results, and I need to have xpath or any other locator for summarize all links on results page? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were doing this for a google search, first I would get the XPath of a single link. You can do this in Chrome by right clicking a link and selecting `Inspect Element`, then right clicking the newly selected element, and then hitting `Copy XPath`. Example:

[image: Select xpath]

I get `//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/li[1]/div/h3/a` from clicking that. However, this will only select a single element, because of `li[1]` and `div[1]`, which limit the query. You probably want to change the XPath to `//*[@id="rso"]/div/li/div/h3/a`, which selects all 10 search results.